# Qual a diferença entre 'dump' e 'dumps' do modulo Pickle em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Já li a documentação do Python e também a do próprio Pickle, mas não consegui assimilar o conteúdo(falta de exemplos). Na Web só encontrei informações sobre como usar o "dump + load" e nada sobre "dumps + loads"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O dump, e load - cada um tomam como parâmetro um arquivo aberto (ou outro objeto com a interface de arquivo) - e salvam o conteúdo serializado do objeto nesse arquivo; (ou o carregam dele, no caso do load).

Já o "dumps" não tem o parâmetro equivalente ao arquivo e devolve o objeto serializado como uma string de bytes . O Loads toma uma string de bytes como parâmetro e devolve o objeto reconstruído. São usados para quando você não vai gravar o resultado do pickle num arquivo imediatamente, mas, por exemplo, está serializando objetos para transmiti-los pela rede, ou para outro processo.

A biblioteca padrão do Python usa bastante o dumps e loads internamente, justamente em módulos como o multiprocessing, para passar objetos de forma transparente para outros processos.

```
>>> a = {"b": ["c", "d", {1,2,3}, ({"e": "f"})]}
>>> print a
{'b': ['c', 'd', set([1, 2, 3]), {'e': 'f'}]}
>>> import pickle
>>> b = pickle.dumps(a)
>>> repr(b)
'"    (dp0\\nS\'b\'\\np1\\n(lp2\\nS\'c\'\\np3\\naS\'d\'\\np4\\nac__builtin__\\nset\\np5\\n((lp6\\nI1\\naI2\\naI3\\natp7\\nRp8\\na(dp9\\nS\'e\'\\np10\\nS\'f\'\\np11\\nsas."'
>>> c = pickle.loads(b)
>>> c == a
True
>>> c is a
False
```

Outros módulos de serialização imitam a interface do pickle, e tem os 4 métodos: dump, dumps, load e loads - é o caso do módulo "json" e o "marshall". O json cria um objeto serializado conforme a especificção [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), que é Javascript sintáticamente válido, quase Python sintáticamente válido e intercambiável com várias linguagens - no entanto só pode serializar um subconjunto dos tipos nativos de dados do Python (strings unicode, números inteiros e floats, booleanos, None, listas e dicionários - outras sequências são convertidas para listas) - Já o marshall pode serializar todos os tipos de dados nativos do Python: listas, dicionários, conjuntos (sets), números complexos, etc... mas vai falahr com objetos definidos em classes em Python puro - mesmo que estejam na biblioteca padrão, como por exemplo OrderedDict, namedtuple, e vários outros.

O Pickle por sua vez vai serializar quase tudo o que estiver na frente - inclusive objetos de classes definidas no seu próprio código,e  funções - (com alguns poréns: quem desserializa tem que "conhecer" os nomes das funções e classes dos objetos serializados)

Por fim, se você realmente quiser serializar coisas malucas - inclusive funções com seu conteúdo (objeto de "code"), há um módulo no Pypi que funciona em cima do Pickle e dá suporte a isso: o [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) (e adivinhe: ele tem load, lods, dump e dumps)

(Cuidado com "load" e "dump": eles devem usar arquivos abertos no modo binário, nunca em modo texto - principalmente no Python 3.x)

Comment: Quando for persistir poucos dados como uma frase por exemplo, o que é mais rápido, usar o pickle ou salvar como string num arquivo de texto? Me refiro em desempenho de processamento.

Comment: Se for só texto, o melhor é codifica em utf-8 e gravar direto num arquivo texto mesmo. 

Ou use o módulo "shelve" da biblioteca padrão: ele te dá um objeto dictionary-like, mas que é persistido de forma transparente no disco (ele usa o pickle internamente, mas você nem precisa saber disso)